# Problems compiling on "architecture x86_64" for JSON1 extension on SQLite

Tags: macos, sqlite, sqlite-json1

There are lots of threads that have similar questions, but many deal with c++ code and have c++ solutions. However, from what I gather on the various threads, I might be missing a library when gcc is trying to link libraries.

I don't know which library I need to include though, for JSON1 to build successfully.

For loading SQLite extensions, their [official instructions on the **Mac**](http://sqlite.org/loadext.html#build) is:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib YourCode.c -o YourCode.dylib
```

So I have done:

```
$ gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib sqlite-src-3180000/ext/misc/json1.c -o json1

sqlite-src-3180000/ext/misc/json1.c:344:11: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'sqlite3_value_subtype' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      if( sqlite3_value_subtype(pValue)==JSON_SUBTYPE ){
          ^
sqlite-src-3180000/ext/misc/json1.c:501:3: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'sqlite3_result_subtype' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  sqlite3_result_subtype(pCtx, JSON_SUBTYPE);
  ^
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_result_subtype", referenced from:
      _jsonArrayFunc in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonExtractFunc in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonObjectFunc in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonQuoteFunc in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonArrayFinal in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonObjectFinal in json1-5de683.o
      _jsonReturnJson in json1-5de683.o
      ...
  "_sqlite3_value_subtype", referenced from:
      _jsonAppendValue in json1-5de683.o
  "_sqlite3_vsnprintf", referenced from:
      _jsonPrintf in json1-5de683.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I missing?

This is my gcc details, if it helps:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```